# Redirect the edit profile page of Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, buddypress

My client is using *Buddypress* on his Wordpress site, but he don't want users to edit their profile in *Buddypress*.

Also he don't want users to go to their `/profile/edit` page when clicking on the *adminbar*.

So I'm looking for a way to change the url in de adminbar to the profile view page,or a way to redirect the `profile/edit` page to the profile view page.

So from: http://[website-url]/members/[username]/profile/edit/

To: http://[website-url]/members/[username]/

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
<?php $classes = get_body_class();

   if (in_array('profile-edit',$classes)) {     
       wp_redirect( bp_loggedin_user_domain() ); exit;
    };

?>
```

This code calls the class of the body. If the body class has 'profile-edit' in it then the wp_redirect function is called. This function asks for the url of the BuddyPress loggedin user profile page and sent him to that page.